# Доступ к вкладке браузера network из приложения

Tags: javascript, webapi

Можно ли получить доступ к вкладке консоли браузера "Network" из приложения (или любому другому объекту, содержащему такую же информацию)? Если "да", то как?

Comment: В вопросе явно не хватает подробностей. Я думаю, что вы имеете в виду вкладку в консоли браузера. Коли так - уточните это в вопросе. Ну или напишите что именно вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, именно это и имею ввиду...дополнил